# Regular Expression - Phone Number - Android

Tags: android, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression to check to see if a valid phone number has been entered.  There is something wrong with my regular expression.  Here is the source code I'm using:

```
if (!Pattern.matches("(\\d{3}-){1,2}\\d{4}", s)) {
                    et.setError("Enter a valid Phone Number");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Instead of making your own regexp, you can use Android's built in method

[`PhoneNumberUtils.isGlobalPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#isGlobalPhoneNumber%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: this methods accepts 0000000000 as a valid mobile no.

Comment: Yes, that's valid. `0000000000` is my phone number, give me a call :)

Comment: This method is TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneNumber) and  don't work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This was the regular expression that fixed the issue:

```
(\\+[0-9]+[\\- \\.]*)?" + "(\\([0-9]+\\)[\\- \\.]*)?" + "([0-9][0-9\\- \\.]+[0-9])
```